# Angular Material | Check if dialog is open

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using the [Angular Material dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) to show a warning message in my app.

I need to check if a dialog is already open like this:

```
private _openDialog() {
  // if (this.dialog.isOpen()) return; <-- NOT WORKING
  this.dialog.open(WarningComponent, {
    width: '450px',
    height: '380px',
  });
```

}

**Question:** Is there any way to check if a Angular Material Dialog box is already open?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If it is in a single component, just store the ref. Useful for manipulating it.

```
private _openDialog() {
  if (!this.dialogRef) return;
  this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(WarningComponent, {
    width: '450px',
    height: '380px',
  });

  this.dialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(
    finalize(() => this.dialogRef = undefined)
  );
}
```

if it's across components, check for the list of opened dialogs :

```
private _openDialog() {
  if (!this.dialog.openDialogs || !this.dialog.openDialogs.length) return;
  this.dialog.open(WarningComponent, {
    width: '450px',
    height: '380px',
  });
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a boolean flag?

Comment: If you already know how to do it, why are you asking ... And yes you can, but using those ways give you a dialog reference, which means you can close the dialog if you want to. A boolean doesn't allow that.

Comment: Using a boolean flag adds many lines of codes. Was looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: You're the one that brought up the boolean flag, I didn't --' And you mean to tell me that using JQuery in encapsuated components is cleaner than usnig the [official documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialog) ? Sure ... Well good luck with your "clean" project.

Comment: Angular and jQuery is a rather powerful combination. I don't see any good solution in the official documentation. Can you be more specific? About the boolean flag: Your solution is nothing more than a flag (being a reference instead of a boolean). Thanks for the help though!

Comment: It keeps getting better ! That's the second solution I provided, using `openDialogs`. A flag is a boolean, my solution isn't a flag. The solution you choose to implement doesn't allow you to close the dialog, and if the class changes, you have to change your own code, making you relying on the implementation of a library (in case you didn't know, previous class started with md- instead of mat-). But then again, you said JQuery and angular are a good pair ... So I don't really need to explain you best practices. Glad you got help, good luck with your project.

Comment: Okay, I see now that your second solution is best. You are correct about the problem if class name changes, the code breaks. Please edit and delete the first example, then I'll accept your answer. Once again thank you for your help!

Comment: The first example is even more relevant than the second one in the case that you face, which is in a single component (if I'm not mistaken). I'm not going to edit my complete answer to provide an incomplete one ... I'm here to help people, and some people might want the first solution rather than the second one. And I don't mind upvotes and reputation, as you can see I have some already. My goal is really to help newcomers resolve issues that I faced. If you use the other solution, then keep it as the valid one !

Comment: Can you please explain how the first example is in any way better than the second? I don't see it.

Comment: Because the second example gives a reference to an array of currently opened dialogs, and not the dialog currently opened by the component. This means you can't know which dialog belongs to your component, and you might close one that you wanted to keep opened. But then again, it is relative to what you do, and since I can't know what you want to do, I'd prefer leaving the two answers and let people decide what they want to implement.

Comment: Ok, but I cant remove my downwote unless the answer is edited.. SO rules.. Sorry for the mess

Comment: Did it, simply added a sentence!

Comment: just in case if the second condition is not working for someone, add length != 0. It should work after that.

Comment: it is considered a bad practice to set anything to "undefined", a better way would be "null"

Comment: thank you for this simple solution! just check if the ref is there or not, no need to try an access an "is open" property.

Answer (score 22):

You can use the `getState()` method on the `MatDialogRef`:

```
const matDialogRef = this.matDialog.open(MyDialogComponent);
if(this.matDialogRef.getState() === MatDialogState.OPEN) {
    // The dialog is opened.
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use this.dialog.getDialogById:

```
        const dialogExist = this.dialog.getDialogById('message-pop-up');

        if (!dialogExist) {
          this.dialog.open(MessagePopUpComponent, {
            id: 'message-pop-up',
            data: // some data
          });
        }
```

Comment: To add to the item above, getDialogById returns the dialogRef to the dialog.
This also means you can subscribe to the closing of the dialog if the dialog is already open, thus meaning that several different items could be waiting on the result.

I had a login dialog that was presented on a 401 return, but clearly with rest, sometimes several calls where made - it meant that all could retry after the log in had occured and the dialog was closed.

Answer (score 6):

My solution was to declare a boolean

```
public isLoginDialogOpen: boolean = false; // I know by default it's false

public openLoginDialog() {

if (this.isLoginDialogOpen) {
  return;
}

this.isLoginDialogOpen = true;

this.loginDialogRef = this.dialog.open(LoginDialogComponent, {
  data: null,
  panelClass: 'theme-dialog',
  autoFocus: false
});

this.loginDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  this.isLoginDialogOpen = false;
  console.log('The dialog was closed');
});
}
```

Comment: If this is a component, you should make the isLoginDialogOpen a singleton. Otherwise if there is more than one instance you could still open it twice.