# Check if mat-dialog is already open

Tags: angular, typescript, mat-dialog

**Goal**: Open dialog on page load. Check to make sure its not already open so it only opens once. The dialog is a separate component.

**Problem**: Its opening twice.

I tried checking, but the condition never becomes true. I was using information from SO articles like [Angular Material | Check if dialog is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52259332/angular-material-check-if-dialog-is-open)
but they mention MatDialogRef ?

**TS**:

```
  ngOnInit()  
  {   
    
    // Set InActiveV back to false incase p refreshes page so that chat will call StartPVQueue
    sessionStorage.setItem('InActiveV', "false");

    // Start visit in API and get medical info    
    const staring = timer(500, 10000);
    this.startVSubscription = staring.subscribe(val =>{
      if (!this.isLoad) {
        this.PStartV();
        //this.cmdOpenDialog_OnInit();
      }
      else {
        this.startVSubscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    });
      this.cmdOpenDialog_OnInit();
  }

cmdOpenDialog_OnInit() {
    if (!this.dialog) {
                return;
            }
    this.dialog.open(DialogInternalNotesThreeComponent, {
        data: {
            data: this.internalNotes
        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store a reference to the dialog on your component:

```
cmdOpenDialog_OnInit() {
  if(this.dialogRef) {
    return;
  }
  this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogInternalNotesThreeComponent, {...});
  this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
    this.dialogRef = null;
  })
}
```

Comment: This did not end up working out, it still created two dialogs

Comment: I need more context to be able to help further. Can you post the component and template files, or an example on stackblitz?

Comment: The method is being called from ngOnInit. I see the line inside of ngOnInit that calls this gets hit twice.

Comment: I added some more code